# Guava ComparisonChain why does it not terminate after first compare returns non-zero result

Tags: java, guava, comparisonchain

Is the comparison chain in guava not supposed to evaluate the compares lazily ? In the below code the NullComparator (apache) would return a non-zero value , should the chain not terminate ?

From the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) : 
the ComparisonChain implementation stops calling its inputs' compareTo and compare methods as soon as one of them returns a nonzero result

```
    String x = null;
    String y = "y";
    ComparisonChain.start().compare(x,y, new NullComparator(false)).
            compare(x.getBytes().toString(), y.getBytes().toString()).result();
```

note: the above was just an example . maybe this would be the better example

```
ComparisonChain.start().compare(x,y, new NullComparator(false)).
        compare(x.getBytes(), y.getBytes(), UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator()).result();
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't terminate?

Comment: throws a npe on the second compare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing can stop Java from evaluating the *arguments* to `compare()`, even if the method does nothing.  `x.getBytes()` will throw an NPE because `x` is `null`.

Perhaps this would work?

```
return Ordering.onResultOf(new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String input) {
                return input.getBytes().toString();
            }
        })
        .nullsFirst()
        .compare(x, y);
```

Keep in mind though that `input.getBytes().toString()` is likely to not make very much sense to sort by (it will look like `[B@35c41b`).

Comment: yes, i am using UnsignedBytes.lexicographicalComparator ..this was just a quick example. i will clarify in the question

Answer (score 3):

That's because what is lazy is the call to compare, not the call to x.getBytes(), hence the NPE !
ie:

```
ComparisonChain.start()
  .compare(x,y, new NullComparator(false))
  .compare(x.getBytes().toString(), y.getBytes().toString()) // <-- tries to invoke compare with two objects
  .result();
```

You should try with a Comparator, which like this :

```
ComparisonChain.start()
  .compare(x,y, new NullComparator(false))
  .compare(x, y, new Comparator<String>() {
    int compare(String a, String b) {
      return a.getBytes().toString().compareTo(b.getBytes().toString());
    }
  })
  .result();
```

Or with Java 8 :

```
ComparisonChain.start()
  .compare(x,y, new NullComparator(false))
  .compare(x, y, (a, b) -> a.getBytes().toString().compareTo(b.getBytes().toString()))
  .result();
```

Note that, comparing `getBytes().toString()` in real situations might not be a good idea...

Comment: yes, thanks for the note. this was just an example ;)

Comment: thanks, accepted the other answer because the Ordering.on was what I was looking for.